# node.js / mac terminal - installing npm

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal

Im trying to install npm for a to start a new project.

When i enter npm install, i get the following error in my terminal:

```
path.js:1086
          cwd = process.cwd();
                        ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, uv_cwd
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1086:25)
    at Function.Module._resolveLookupPaths (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:479:17)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:574:20)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:145:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
```

Comment: have you checked your terminal has permission to access your project directory?

Comment: i checked the folder im trying to add Node to and it is listed as read-write permission, if that's what you are referring to. Im using bash in my terminal so not sure if i need to run a different command to start a new node.js project

Comment: i finally figured it out. you were right. my terminal did not have access to my project folder(s) @Tharunkumar thank-you!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Go to System Preferences/Security & Privacy/Full Disk Access
And give permission to the terminal, you must write your password

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the terminal has permission to access the folder.
[Here](http://kb.yworks.com/article/784/Installation-Issue-on-macOS---EPERM-operation-not-permitted-uvcwd) is good documentation that can he